# Is it able to hide the icon in the iOS App Monaca Debugger?

Tags: monaca

I´m using the Monaca Debugger for iOS to debug my Apps.
The Monaca Debugger adds a "square-Icon" with controls for the Debugger.
Is it possible, to hide the icon?

Thank you
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, at the moment there is no way to disable it as it contains a set of mandatory functionalities for debugging. Also, if it was possible to disable it, you would have no way to get back in the debugger main page.